# How to take a string and output how many: spaces, uppercase, lowercase etc

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

So I want to be able to take a string and output the following: Uppercase, lowercase, digits, periods, commas, blanks, and other symbols. I have most of the code done, but I have commented at the area that I am having trouble with. I cannot how to do this, and it has stumped me for the better part of a week! Would appreciate any help!

```
import java.util.*;

public class JavaPractice
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        //declarations

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        char tryAgain = 'n';
        char linechar = ' ';
        String lineText;
        int uppercase = 0;
        int lowercase = 0;
        int digits = 0;
        int periods = 0;
        int commas = 0;
        int blanks = 0;
        int others = 0;


       do
       {
          // initialize categories       
          uppercase = 0;
          lowercase = 0;
          digits = 0;
          periods = 0;
          commas = 0;
          blanks = 0;
          others = 0;

          // user input 
          System.out.println("Enter a line of text:");
          lineText = keyboard.nextLine();

          // This is where I would like to count the number of spaces, uppercase ETC where I am having the most trouble


          // print output    

          System.out.println("Uppercase:") + (uppercase);

          System.out.println("Lowercase:") + (lowercase);

          System.out.println("Digits:") + (digits)

          System.out.println("Periods:") + (periods);

          System.out.println("Commas:") + (commas);

          System.out.println("Blanks:") + (blanks);

          System.out.println("Other Symbols":) + (others);

          // try again        

          System.out.println("Would you like to try again y/n?");

          tryAgain = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);

        } while (tryAgain == 'y' || tryAgain == 'Y'); //end while loop

        System.out.println("GoodBye");

    } //end main()
} //end JavaPractice
```

Comment: You might want to mention *how* you're having trouble.

Comment: More specifically, you might want to actually try to code something and not come here with a blank area...

Answer (score 6):

- Start by converting the `String` to a `char` array, see [`String#toCharArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29).  You could also use [`String#charAt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29), `toCharArray` will make it easier to iterate over the characters.
- Create a [`for-loop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) to loop of the `char` array.
- For each `char` use, [`Character#isWhiteSpace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29), [`Character#isLowerCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLowerCase%28char%29), [`Character#isUpperCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase%28char%29), [`Character#isDigit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29), [`Character#isLetter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29) or compare it with whatever other `char` you need to look for.  This will involve some kind of [`if-else`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) statement

Answer (score 0):

First make String into array of Chars.

For uppercase and lowercase, you can make a loop from A - Z when the char is equal you increment the counter.

For period, comma and blank you can do the same. That is you loop the length of the String and find the occurences for period, comma and blank. For more advance solution you may look at RegEx.

Answer (score -1):

I would use the split function in the `String` class which returns an array based on splitting the string on a particular regex input.

consider for example the following `String`

```
String input="hello.world";

// use different delimeters
// splitting the input based on a comma
String[] test = input.split(","); 

// test will now have the value test[0] = hello , test[1]= world

int length = test.length - 1 // test.length = 2, you need to subtract 2 because the length of the array will always be 1 more than the number of occurences, so if the number of occurances is n the length of the array is n+1.
```

You can similarly split based on other characters.

Comment: Don't see how this helps, unless the input looks like "a,b,c,d,e, ...".  (BTW, your delimiters don't match up.  So `test` will only contain the one string `"hello.world"`.)  Even then, at some point, you still need chars in order to determine the type.

Comment: it was just a hacky solution for the asker to understand string functions .the string splits based on the delimiter parameter . if you maintain an input string and perform the actions on a copy string yuou can do it for all . I agree it is not the most memory efficient solution

Comment: Memory efficiency isn't the issue here.  The issue is: *ok, you've split the string.  Congrats.  Now what?*  The splitting didn't get you any closer at all to the goal -- you just have a bunch of substrings to have to count.  And anything that will work for those substrings, should also work for the unsplit string.  Splitting really just complicates the matter, if you're not trying to count something bigger than a character (words, for example).